# TDE template derived from Person example fails

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using MarkLogic 9 and following the tutorial about SQL Datamodeling Guide ( https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/intro ) Al pre conditions are met:

1. Installing MarkLogic 9 on Cent Os  (Done without errors )
2. Create forests   (Done without errors )
3. Create databases (Done without errors )
4. Insert data      (Done without errors )

Until i reach to create a template view ( https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/setup#id_14127 ) When i execute the statement in the query console i got the following error:

```
[1.0-ml] SVC-FILOPN: File open error: open '/MarkLogic/tde.xqy': No 

such file or directory
Stack Trace

At line 2 column 0:
In xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;; &#10;import module namespace ...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>18182129315596444747</database>...</options>)
1. xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
2. import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" 
3. at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";
```

The files of MarkLogic are placed in the folder ./opt/MarkLogic and the directory has the folow

```
erik@marklogic-vm /opt/MarkLogic $ ls -l
total 460
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  53248 Apr 14 19:40 Admin
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Apps
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Assets
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  20480 Apr 14 19:40 Config
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Converters
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Docs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 FlexRep
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  35147 Apr 11 09:08 GPL.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 HealthCheck
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 include
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Installer
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 java
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  12288 Apr 14 19:40 Lang
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 250564 Apr 11 09:08 LEGALNOTICES.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  18416 Apr 11 09:08 LGPL21.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   7639 Apr 11 09:08 LGPL30.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Messages
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 mlcmd
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Modules
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 11 09:58 Plugins
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   4096 Apr 14 19:40 Samples
```

Have you any idea what goes wrong ?

Manny thanks

Erik

Comment: Well, obviously there is no such file `'/MarkLogic/tde.xqy'` (at least it can not be read be ML). This is what the error message is already telling you. I am not sure how we can elaborate here...

Comment: Dirkk thanks for the fast reply! I just need a solution on this error! Indeed i know what ML tells me! Only i dint know how i can solve this error!

Comment: You put this file where ML expects it...? Or you change the path?

Comment: Sorry to ask a dumb question- you are running this against an installation of ML9 and not a previous version? What OS are you running on?

Comment: Did you make any changes to the default installation? My ML9 instance on MacOS has no problem finding the library at /MarkLogic/tde.xqy. Something isn't right with your installation/setup.

Comment: Harry i use Cent Os for ml 9.

Comment: Harry i update the question with aditional information. The file is not placed in the directory. Is it posible to download the file somewhere. Or can you post the definiton in the Answer? Many thanks Erik

Comment: @Erikhoeven - can you confirm your ML version (via the Admin Interface) - it should be "9.0-1.1".

Comment: @Erikhoeven - also I had some issues when I did an upgrade, did you do a clean install of ML9 or did you upgrade from an earlier version?

Comment: I did a upgrade!

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are running MarkLogic 9.0-1.1, rather than MarkLogic 9.0-1?

Comment: I have indeed MarkLogic 9.0-1. So i thing i must deinstall and download the latest edition

Comment: Please do report back about whether that fixes the problem

Comment: Keep in mind libraries are stored within /opt/MarkLogic/Modules/, so check if /opt/MarkLogic/Modules/MarkLogic/tde.xqy exists. Also note that upgrades from Early-Access releases are not supported. If you ran ML9-ea before, I'd recommend wiping out MarkLogic (e.g. recursive delete /var/opt/MarkLogic/, which deletes all data including Security database) before installing latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erik - when using the `tde:template-insert()` function in your Query Console, make sure that you have your 'content' database selected (in your case this would be the SQLData) and not the SQLSchema database. Executing the `template-insert()` function against the SQLData database will insert the template to the SQLSchema database.

Also, please make sure that your SQLData database has the SQLSchema database associated with it.

We, at MarkLogic, have also just recently released a 4 hour, self-paced course on all new MarkLogic 9 features - including TDE. Please take a look at it - http://www.marklogic.com/training-courses/whats-new-marklogic-9/ - it will definitely help you to get up to speed with the latest additions to the database. (You can also get an assessment done at the end of the course).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the help and reaction. It seems i had previous verion of MarkLogic which TDE is not yet supported. I removed ML comppletly and install ML 9.0 XX

1. Create one database SQLData and a forest forest-SQL-Data
2. Set the property triple index at enable
3. Create one database SQLSchema and a forest SQLSchema
4. In the query console in the SQLData database in run the folowing query for creating the view:

> ```
> xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
>
> import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" 
>        at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";
>
> let $employees :=
> <template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
>   <context>/Employee</context>
>   <rows>
>     <row>
>       <schema-name>main</schema-name>
>       <view-name>employees</view-name>
>       <columns>
>         <column>
>           <name>EmployeeID</name>
>           <scalar-type>int</scalar-type>
>           <val>ID</val>
>         </column>
>         <column>
>           <name>FirstName</name>
>           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
>           <val>FirstName</val>
>         </column>
>         <column>
>           <name>LastName</name>
>           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
>           <val>LastName</val>
>         </column>
>         <column>
>           <name>Position</name>
>           <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
>           <val>Position</val>
>         </column>
>        </columns>
>     </row>
>   </rows>
> </template>
>
> return tde:template-insert("/employees.xml", $employees)
> ```

It does not work if you run this in the SQLSchema database.